# IIS Url Rewrite, Localhost Only (missing files and folders)

Tags: iis, rewrite

We work with websites that are occasionally copied into a local environment for routine debugging, etc.

These sites have lots of user generated media - specifically images. To avoid downloading all these files, we have a simple redirect rule, so any files/folders in a certain folder that return 404, get redirected to the production server.

**The Problem**

The rule should only be applied when the website is running on localhost.
*e.g. condition: request is localhost.*

```
<!-- Handle missing files or folders inside   
     the /Media directory on Development Environment -->

<rule name="Handle missing media" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="^media/(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />                    
        <!-- Add Conditions, so local only -->
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Temporary" 
            url="http://production.domain/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" />
</rule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have a machine to test this right now, but I guess an additional condition like this should work:

```
<conditions>
     <add input="{REMOTE_ADDR}" pattern="127.0.0.1" />
</conditions>
```

or even:

```
<conditions>
    <add input="{REMOTE_HOST}" pattern="localhost" />
</conditions>
```